# Maven higher level tooling, for debugging/visualizing/stepping through complex POM flows

Tags: maven, tooling

I've recently found that poms I deal with are increasingly complicated, with submodules, multiple steps that can fail due to platform specific (non-java) related bugs, etc...

Since maven's functionality is now more sophisticated, has any tooling arrived that will allow us to debug / step through a maven build, mojo by mojo, or for example, module by module?  At the moment, I usually resort to running builds and scanning, by eye, for errors in the rather verbose output of the standard mvn incantations.

Answer (score 0):

mvn "your parameters list" | grep -i "your error phrase" ?
That's what I'm using ...

Comment: well certainly theres always grep.  but, im talking about visualizeing complicated submodule dependencies and visualizing the non-trivial information in effective poms, etc..

Comment: mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=[groupId]:[artifactId]:[type]:[version] -Dexcludes=[groupId]:[artifactId]:[type]:[version] ? It would help to filter in your undesired classes ...